# Number formator - Java

Tags: java

I have a number 100000. I need to display like 1,00,000. How can I achieve this **without** using the string manipulation functions in Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to use a string manipulation function. Why wouldn't you want to? And Javascript/jQuery is very different from Java.

Comment: If we have in Jquery or Javascript. I can control it in front end. If we have in java, I can use it in back end.

Comment: Okay, but why wouldn't you want to use string manipulation functions and why is that important?

Comment: -1 This question makes no sense, and the tags less so. Please take time to make sure it doesn't cover "multiple unrelate languages", at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NumberFormat` implementation or `DecimalFormat` class available in Java.

e.g.

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##,####");
String value = dFormat.format(100000);
System.out.println("Formatted Value="+value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick google and I got this from [here](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html).

*This functionality is not built into JavaScript, so custom code needs to be used. The following is one way of adding commas to a number, and returning a string.*

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
function addCommas(num) {return (""+num).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,',');}
```

For a more complete version, which includes support for decimal numbers of arbitrary precision, see [`numbar_format` on PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Java that only uses string methods to find length and character position, if you're still interested.

```
   int counter = 0; 
   int number=123456789;
   String str = Integer.toString(number);
   String finalStr = new String();

   for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
       counter++;
       if(counter % 3 == 0 && i != 0){
           finalStr = ","+str.charAt(i)+finalStr;
       }
       else{
           finalStr = str.charAt(i)+finalStr;
       }
   }

   System.out.println("Final String: "+finalStr);
```

It uses the length of the value to loop down and builds the new string from the right to the left.  At every third value (except the final one), it will add a comma before the string.  Otherwise, it will continue on and build the string in the interim values between commas.

So this would print to the console:

> Final String: 123,456,789